# In PowerShell how to make cd directory tab completion without leading dot+slash?

Tags: powershell

In bash when I do `$ cd fo`<kbd>TAB</kbd> I get `$ cd foo/`. In PowerShell I get `$ cd ./foo/` instead. How to tell PowerShell to not decorate relative directory name with "dot and slash" prefix? (`foo` is a subdirectory, <kbd>TAB</kbd> means pressing tab key, and obviously PS uses backslash instead of slash).

I have `Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs` in my profile.

Comment: Does the ./ cause technical issues or is it for aesthetic reasons?

Comment: Well, mostly aesthetics, but recently I have added git submodule to some repository and the path to to the subrepository was prefixed, and when I pulled the repo on a remote machine (Linux) git couldn't find the submodule (I hade to change it manually)

Comment: [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264655/how-to-make-powershell-tab-completion-work-like-bash) may help.

Comment: didn't help, read this before

Comment: This is not only irritating, it also breaks some applications. Let's say I'm running `foo.exe`. So if I type `fo` and hit `Tab`, PowerShell puts `.\foo.exe`. Fine; that's to run the program. But if I want to pass an argument to `foo.exe`, such as `bar.dat`, when I hit `Tab` for `ba` I get `.\foo.exe .\bar.dat`, which I don't want—I want `.\foo.exe bar.dat`. In fact the particular `foo.exe` I'm working with won't accept `.\bar.dat`, only `bar.dat`. This is annoying. Is there some solution? Otherwise I'm switch back to `cmd`.